# Any games based on Warp/OTE out there?

Tags: over-the-edge, warp

Atlas Games has recently made the [Over the Edge core rules available as OGL](http://www.atlas-games.com/warp/).

Are there any games using it? Even if not yet available (i.e. still under design/playtest) I would like to see what direction it is going, if any.

Also, if you have some already existing example of using OTE rules in a completely different background I'd be very interested in having a look.

(I am already aware of the [Thundarr the Barbarian unofficial conversion to OTE](http://www.rpglibrary.org/settings/thundarr/), but I am looking for more)

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I reached out to Cam Banks (Atlas Games' brand manager) on Google+ and he indicated that he was unaware of any games at this time.