# Games that use Mongoose Traveller's Game Engine

Tags: traveller

I've read (the free version of) Worlds Apart - a fantasy system using "Traveller System Reference Document Copyright © 2008, Mongoose Publishing".

I.e. an adaptation of core Traveller mechanics (as described in Mongoose edition), including careers and ship building, to a fantasy archipelago world.

My question: are there games from other companies that use the Traveller game engine?

Comment: The title of this question does not evoke its content, and it is easily answered with a Google search. Were you instead looking  for how the game varies in each iteration...?

Comment: Can you please show me the google search you suggest? I tried a few but all these only return Worlds Apart (often in the second or third page) the rest are links to different Traveller editions, or to Mongoose itself. If you want to retitle the question so that it's more evocative, that's fine for me.

Comment: Using "Mongoose Traveller" as my search criteria, the first hit takes me to Mongoose's catalog page where it lists all the games they make and sell using Traveller: http://www.mongoosepublishing.com/rpgs/traveller.html   The second hit is their forum. Your comment suggests that what you actually want is non-Mongoose licenses of their system, such as Zozer's Orbital or Outpost Mars? You are right that would be harder to filter out.

Comment: Orbital and Outpost Mars are supplements, not standalone games.

Comment: @aramis: so is Worlds Apart the only currently existing game using the engine?

Comment: @p.marino it's the only one I've ever heard of - and only from your question -  yet. And I'm an admin on one of the largest Traveller sites on the net. Even Mongoose isn't producing related rulesets - only supplements. 2300 isn't stand-alone. Nor are Dredd, Strontium Dog, or Hammers Slammers.

Comment: This is my second attempt (http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/15276/any-games-based-on-warp-ote-out-there) at finding out if my favourite rule engines have been officially used for something different (I'd like a contemporary Traveller, to be used for something like CORPS "Deathwind", for example... granted, just using things up to TL9 could work with just the normal rules, but I'd like to see a complete treatment from a real publisher.

Answer (score 3):

Even Mongoose themselves publish several distinct games based on their Traveller engine - Judge Dread and Strontium Dog being the two I think of straight away.

Comment: -1 Neither of those is a standalone game. In fact, very few adaptations use the MGT engine - in no small part because what was left out of the SRD was very much core - the careers themselves, and weapon damages. Which means you need to use different damages if you want to do a new, truly core, rulebook.